# NSArray Duplicate array from A struct Array (Swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, class, struct

I managed to read few things about the possibility of duplicating array from other classes using the NSObject class type and specifically NSArray..

I have a String array in a normal struct of type :View

**e.g**

```
  struct ClassName: View {
    var data = [String]() 
  }
```

I want to duplicate this array's values into another array of type NSArray in my separate NSObject Class..
How would I go about doing this..

I implemented a NSObject class with this code:

```
    class copyArray: NSObject {
var copiedArray: NSArray = NSArray()
var data : ClassName = ClassName()
```

Not sure what to do next..

Comment: Why `NSArray`? Why `NSObject`?

Comment: @vadia Hi,  because I need to duplicate the array into another swift file. I was told the only way to do this is via NSObject..

Comment: Swift `Array` duplicates its values by default when being copied. And what does *duplicate the array into another swift file* mean?

Comment: @vadian I have two Swift Files, one is FileOne.swift and another is FileTwo.swift. Both are in the same project.